# AWS Sentiment Analysis tutorial using Naive Bayes Classifier

Tags: python, hadoop, sentiment-analysis, amazon-emr, naivebayes

I am following the AWS Sentiment Analysis tutorial from [here](http://awsdocs.s3.amazonaws.com/gettingstarted/latest/awsgsg-emr.pdf).

The problem I am having is, the classifier is never finding negative tweets. It always displays only the positive and neutral ones like this,

```
kindle: positive     492
No match:              8
```

The dataset is obtained using the tweepy library. And I am using the following python code for as the mapper,

**Mapper Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cPickle as pickle
import nltk.classify.util
from nltk.classify import NaiveBayesClassifier
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
import sys

sys.stderr.write("Started mapper.\n");


def word_feats(words):
    return dict([(word, True) for word in words])


def subj(subjLine):
    subjgen = subjLine.lower()
    # Replace term1 with your subject term
    subj1 = "kindle"
    if subjgen.find(subj1) != -1:
        subject = subj1
        return subject
    else:
        subject = "No match"
        return subject


def main(argv):
    classifier = pickle.load(open("classifier.p", "rb"))
    for line in sys.stdin:
        tolk_posset = word_tokenize(line.rstrip())
        d = word_feats(tolk_posset)
        subjectFull = subj(line)
        if subjectFull == "No match":
            print "LongValueSum:" + " " + subjectFull + ": " + "\t" + "1"
        else:
            print "LongValueSum:" + " " + subjectFull + ": " + classifier.classify(d) + "\t" + "1"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

I can read the negative tweets on the dataset, but that is not detected by this example in the tutorial.

How do I troubleshoot to find and display the negative tweets as well in my program - is it a problem with my mapper code or the classifier file?

Comment: I see `d = word_feats(tolk_posset)` --- perhaps you need to load the negative features?

Comment: I think the classifier file from that tutorial is messed up. I tried using another classifier file from here `https://github.com/gwDistSys15/dist-sys-exercises/blob/master/lec-10/hadoop/twitter/movclass.p` and it seems to be working fine.